# Want to learn gtk and glade

Tags: gtk, pygtk, glade

Any links or tutorials viedos link pls suggest me.i tried so many links and tutorials in YouTube but there is no proper way of teaching these courses and I tried Udemy also in that only Spanish language course only available no English language

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is Simon Long's book `An Introduction to C & GUI Programming.` It introduces GTK2, (the latest version is GTK4) but things are essentially the same in the version. You just have to learn the new functions that replace the deprecated. And it has a chapter on Glade. Just skip to the middle of the book, that is where the GTK section is, and it continues to the end of the book. If you have a Raspberry Pi, you can download it on the Bookshelf program for free.